# How to hide table row using button

Tags: javascript

Here I have a sample code of Table Data and i want to hide row(s) using the x button together with the id selector and/or using increment php variable, It is possible using `JavaScript`, `Jquery`, or `CSS`?, Please i need your advice and recommendation

```html
<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <th>Sample Head</th>
        <th>Sample Head</th>
        <th>Sample Head</th>
        <th>Sample Head</th>
        <th>Sample Head</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>  
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td>Sample Data</td>
            <td><button type='submit'>X</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.elemEvent').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if (e.target.tagName=='BUTTON')  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.display='none'
})
```

```html
<table class="elemEvent" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Sample Head</th>
    <th>Sample Head</th>
    <th>Sample Head</th>
    <th>Sample Head</th>
    <th>Sample Head</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 1</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 2</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 3</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 4</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 5</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 6</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 7</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 8</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 9</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 10</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 11</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>Sample Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is it!, Can i change button to link? because button does not work inside the form post

Comment: yep, then instead of  e.target.tagName=='BUTTON' write e.target.tagName=='A'

Comment: what about class? can i change to id?

Comment: There is a better idea, you write html, since you see it.